# How to change the content of a div on a click?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got 4 divs:

- placeholder for media
- slider with images
- video
- 3d embedded model (iframe basically)

And 3 text links:

- images
- video
- 3d

The goal is to change content of the placeholder div with the relative media div depending on the link clicked.

The "solution" which I have right now is to load all of them with position: absolute in a same spot, and depending on a link clicked - change opacity of the div in question to 1 and the rest of div's to 0.

Obviously, this kind of "solution" is not working that well because all of the media being loaded at the same time ... so I was hoping there's a better way to do this.
Help much appreciated.

Comment: Way too broad and unspecific. Yes, you can use JS to switch out/change the content of an element - in a multitude of different ways. Do some proper research.

Comment: Absolute and placed on same spot -> use css Z-index

Comment: you can use the same logic but add  urls for each div to load the content on click.... or you could directly write the divs on click. its a lot easier if you're using jquery.

Comment: If the issue is that all content is loading at the same time, slowing the page, you may just make them `display:none;` and when user clicks links to open one of them - change to `display:block;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, one simple method is to track click events on 
your links and replace the content in your placeholder Div,

```
 $( "#link1" ).click(function() {
  $("#placeHolder").html("link 1 content");
});
```

look at this example I made:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XajOdg

Comment: with this method, do i need to create separate html page for each div with media content?

Comment: no, you don't have to. The html() function means that whatever is within the div will be replaced by the string you send in. So, for example, if you type in:

$("#placeHolder").html("<div> <img href="image-location/img.jpg"/> </div>");

then, the div or any element technically with the ID "placeHolder" will be cleaned (emptied) up and the content you specified as a parameter to your .html() will be put in its place. It's basically a "replace all contents in this element with this" function. 

This uses Jquery by the way.

Comment: not working yet, but i guess it might be syntaxis somewhere. When you say "this uses jquery", do I need to include something else in html?

Comment: you can add this to your HTML: 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
 Or, download and include the jquery js file into your project and then link it to your HTML

Comment: I got animation and things as well, so jquery 3.2.1 was there anyway :) thought i had to include something else ... anyhow, trying to get this to work, no luck so far *sigh*

Comment: Sometimes Jquery events don't know when they should start acting. Did you try putting your code inside a document ready? syntax is here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: yup, it's inside a $(document).ready(function(){  code  });

Comment: i mean it's all working fine with plain text .. however, it doesn't work if I put a <div> into that html(" <div> anything here .. images, text, doesn't matter</div>")

Comment: it was the double quote issue ... after using single 'quotes' within .html, things began to work! many thanks man!

Comment: ah, cool!. I usually thought double quotes weren't an issue there, interesting. It's one of those things you never notice.

Comment: it doesn't like spaces within that .html(' ') as well. had to remove all of the spaces in order for it to work. However, now i'm struggling to get classes applied to the divs that was generated by this .html method. I guess i need to do a refresh somehow

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just change the div element's text by clicking on any element(other div) you can do this..

```
$("#other_div").click(function() {
 $(#div_content_to_be_changed).text("what ever you want");
});
```